How can I overlay an SVG image over a raster image using Python (Python3)?
I have some generated raster images and SVG images (as an ElementTree), but for the sake of the example, let's say that they are saved as files. This is what I am trying to do:
import cv2 as cv
iimport numpy as np
#import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import cairosvg

image = cv.imread('./my_raster.jpeg') #already a (height, width, 3) BGR np.array
png_bytes = cairosvg.svg2png(url='./my_vector.svg') #same size as image
png_image = cv.imdecode(np.frombuffer(png_bytes, np.uint8), cv.IMREAD_COLOR)
alpha = png_image[:, :, 3] / 255.0
ouput_img = cv.addWeighted(image, 1-alpha, png_image[:, :, :3], alpha, 0)

cv.imwrite('./overlayed.jpeg')

However I am having problems with cairosvg
OSError: no library called "cairo-2" was found
no library called "cairo" was found
no library called "libcairo-2" was found
cannot load library 'libcairo.so.2': error 0x7e.  Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'libcairo.so.2'
cannot load library 'libcairo.2.dylib': error 0x7e.  Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'libcairo.2.dylib'
cannot load library 'libcairo-2.dll': error 0x7e.  Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'libcairo-2.dll'

I have nsuccessfuly tried to fix cairosvg but I don't particularly care for that package. Are there other strategies to accomplish the intended result?
Will my idea work if I manage to have cairosvg working?
